# Trying to wrap some flutter code in a try catch block and it errors out

Tags: flutter, android-studio, exception, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Trying to wrap some flutter code in a try catch block and it errors out.

I get the error "Expected a class member.  Try placing this code inside a class member"
Below is mu code snippet

```
``import 'package:http/http.dart';
  import 'dart:convert';

class WorldTime {

  String location; //location name for the UI
  late String time; //time in that location
  String flag; //url to asset flag icon
  String url; //location url for api endpoint

  WorldTime(this.location, this.time, this.flag, this.url);

  try{
  Future<void> getTime() async {
    Response response = await get(
        Uri.parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url'));
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    //print(data);
    String dateTime = data['datetime'];
    String offSet = data['utc_offset'].substring(1, 3);
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(dateTime);
    now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offSet)));
    time = now.toString();
  }
}
  catch(e){

  }
}`
`
```

I've looked at examples online to figure out what i might be doing wrong, but nothing jumps out at me. I'm new to flutter though.

Comment: Put the try statement inside the future before the response line. The catch also must be inside the getTiime method

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this,

```
 Future<void> getTime() async {
      try{
        Response response = await get(
            Uri.parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url'));
        Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        //print(data);
        String dateTime = data['datetime'];
        String offSet = data['utc_offset'].substring(1, 3);
        DateTime now = DateTime.parse(dateTime);
        now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offSet)));
        time = now.toString();
      }catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
    }
```

The `try catch` block should be inside the method `getTime()`.